# Dynamic content from JSON takes 30 seconds to load

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am making a web chat manager very similar to whatsapp web. What I am doing is create a list of chats (not messages) retrieved from a json file. JSON file is near instant and contains almost 1000 Objects in One array.

I perform a function that adds a row in my html for each object. But it is taking 25 seconds to perform. What am I doing wrong?

The code -

```
chatList.forEach((elem, index) => {
        let unreadClass = elem.unreadCount ? "unread" : "";

        DOM.chatList.innerHTML += `
        <div class="chat-list-item d-flex flex-row w-100 p-2 border-bottom ${unreadClass}" onclick="generateMessageArea(this, ${index})">
            <img src="profile.png" alt="Profile Photo" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mr-2" style="height:50px;">
            
            <div class="w-50">
                <div class="name">${elem.contactname}</div>
                <div class="small last-message">Click to Open</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-1 text-right">
            ${elem.unreadCount ? "<div class=\"badge badge-success badge-pill small\" id=\"unread-count\">" + elem.unreadCount + "</div>" : ""}
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
    });
```

ChatList is the parsed json. After taking 25 seconds still it shows white page for about 15 seconds maybe rendering json. I know my code may be really horrible. What should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is you're appending with `.innerHTML +=`; this will parse the *entire* HTML so far, each time an element is added. Use `const div = document.createElement("div");` instead, populate it, assign the classes, etc, then use `DOM.chatlist.append(div);` Alternatively, append to a string instead, then set `innerHTML` to the string once, after the loop.

Comment: For appending strings to the DOM use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `.innerHTML` (only the inserted string gets parsed, event handlers aren't removed from the existing content) + reduce the amount of DOM changes (create one large string and add this instead)

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah I collected content from forEach loop and added it all together to innerhtml. This helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing DOM reflows in a loop. That is what potentially slows your script down.
Read here more: https://medium.com/@imanj12/efficient-dom-access-and-manipulation-f2f8596596b3

To summarize: When you modify innerHTML, your browser has to recalculate positions of all the elements and place them accordingly. That is an expensive operation. Do it frequently and you have a performance issue.

A solution is to use [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to populate your chat list and then append it once to the main DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I just did is put a dummy variable, added all content to it and then added it all together to innerHTML. It reduced time to below 10 seconds which is satisfying for me. The link contains great content.

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're using `.innerHTML`. It's a bad practice to use it in a loop because it makes the browser not only recalculate the styles, but also parse the HTML code into a DOM tree. Also you probably have an XSS vulnerability. You need to escape `elem.contactname`.

I suggest using the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element for performance reasons and modifying the contents using `innerText` to prevent XSS.

```js
const elem = {
  contactname: "[Contact Name]"
},
unreadClass = "unread-class",
index = 0;

const chatTempl = document.getElementById("chat-template");

const clone = chatTempl.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

clone.classList.add(unreadClass);
clone.addEventListener("click", function () {
  generateMessageArea(this, index);
});
clone.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText = elem.contactname;
// etc...

document.body.append(clone);
```

```html
<template id="chat-template">
<div class="chat-list-item d-flex flex-row w-100 p-2 border-bottom">
            <img src="profile.png" alt="Profile Photo" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mr-2" style="height:50px;">
            
            <div class="w-50">
                <div class="name">${elem.contactname}</div>
                <div class="small last-message">Click to Open</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-1 text-right">
            ${elem.unreadCount ? "<div class=\"badge badge-success badge-pill small\" id=\"unread-count\">" + elem.unreadCount + "</div>" : ""}
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: +1 for a different approach but the answer is much simple. Simply add content of for each loop to a dummy variable and put dummy variable in inner html at last.